# What is a pool thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, pstree

When I run `pstree -p pid` on Linux, it displays a thread tree of a process.

Many processes contains threads called "pool". Some of them live a short lifecycle. They look like:

```
tracker-extract(2785)─┬─{dconf worker}(2825)
                      ├─{gdbus}(2826)
                      ├─{gmain}(2827)
                      ├─{pool}(2975)
                      ├─{pool}(2976)
                      ├─{pool}(2977)
                      ├─{pool}(2978)
                      ├─{pool}(2979)
                      ├─{pool}(2980)
                      ├─{pool}(2981)
                      ├─{pool}(2982)
                      ├─{pool}(2983)
                      └─{pool}(2984)
```

What are those "pool" threads? What kind of jobs are they responsible to?

---

It's quite hard to google it. All results come out related to thread pool. Do they have relation with thread pool?

Comment: This isn't really programming related and should probable go on server fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing hints. I finally accidentally use perf and find those pool threads are responsible for thread cloning or something like this.